# Is there another brief way to detect if an item is in a vim list other than `index(L, item)`?

Tags: vim

In python, there is a syntax `i in L` to detect if a value is in a list.
Is there a similar syntax in vim other than `index()` function?

Answer (score 0):

`vim` has no syntax like `i in L` like Python.

But you can make syntax shorter with [count()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#count()) instead of [index()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#index()):

```
:echo count([1, 2, 3], 2)
1
```

Then you can use:

```
if count(L, i)
  echo 'i in L'
endif
```

A note that `count()` will be slower than `index()`, since when it counts all occurrences of `i` in `L`, instead of first index like `index()`.